# Поиск по DataGridView заполняемая от XML

Tags: c#, winforms, xml, datagridview

Есть таблица которая заполняется подобным образом:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(Properties.Settings.Default.XMLDBFile);

foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables["Orders"].Rows)
{
    int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item["Date"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["Service"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item["Quantity"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item["Status"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item["Sum"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = item["Employee"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = item["Term"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[7].Value = item["Client"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[8].Value = item["Comment"].ToString();
}
```

Как это выглядит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А это подгружаемый xml файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Orders>
    <Date>24.06.2020</Date>
    <Service>Услуга 1</Service>
    <Quantity>0 шт.</Quantity>
    <Status>Новый</Status>
    <Sum>0 ₽</Sum>
    <Employee>Сотрудник</Employee>
    <Term>27.06.2020</Term>
    <Client xml:space="preserve"> </Client>
    <Comment />
  </Orders>
  <Orders>
    <Date>24.06.2020</Date>
    <Service>Услуга 2</Service>
    <Quantity>0 шт.</Quantity>
    <Status>Отменен</Status>
    <Sum>0 ₽</Sum>
    <Employee>Сотрудник</Employee>
    <Term>27.06.2020</Term>
    <Client xml:space="preserve"> </Client>
    <Comment />
  </Orders>
  <Orders>
    <Date>24.06.2020</Date>
    <Service>Услуга 3</Service>
    <Quantity>0 шт.</Quantity>
    <Status>Новый</Status>
    <Sum>0 ₽</Sum>
    <Employee>Сотрудник</Employee>
    <Term>27.06.2020</Term>
    <Client xml:space="preserve"> </Client>
    <Comment />
  </Orders>
</NewDataSet>
```

Хочу сделать поиск по столбцу "Услуга".
Вот его код:

```
private void toolStriptbxSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(Properties.Settings.Default.XMLDBFile);
            this.dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Orders"];
            string filterField = "Service";
            ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("[{0}] LIKE '%{1}%'", filterField, toolStriptbxSearch.Text);
        }
```

Когда я набираю что-то в текстовое поле `toolStriptbxSearch` поиск работает, но открывается еще одна таблица:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом это можно исправить?

Comment: Я плохо помню как это в WinForms правильно делать, но по-моему нужно проксировать данные через `CollectionViewSource` и задавать фильтр для нее. По поводу организации наполнения, у вас сделано очень сложно, можно проще. Вот откопал у себя в архивах [пример на Яндекс.Диске](https://yadi.sk/d/EfyCPVKwLshBJg), там показан способ привязки данных к `DGV` через `BindingList`, это сделает ваш код значительно проще. Может вы просто там найдете что-то интересное для себя. Пока это все что у меня есть, может еще кто-то поможет.

Comment: Корень проблемы в том, что вы перечитываете все данные заново, так делать не надо, надо фильтровать уже загруженные.

Comment: Наврал про `CollectionViewSource`, эта тема из WPF. Можно через `DataSource.DefaultView.RowFilter`, вы здесь правильно делаете. Но проблема перезагрузки данных у вас есть, их не надо перезагружать.

Comment: @aepot Благодарю за ответ, осталось понять как их не перезагружать, а использовать уже загруженную. Весь день мучаюсь с этим.

Comment: А почему вы грузите таблицу поячеечно, почему не просто `.DataSource=`?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, если DataGridView привязан к данным, то в него нельзя добавить строки программно.

Comment: Верно, но почему вам нужно добавлять строки програмно? Если DGV можно дать просто нужные данные.

Comment: Я их записываю в DVG, а потом добавляю эти записи в XML. Может я что-то делаю не так, но когда назначен `.DataSourse`, то он не может добавить строки.

Comment: Ну разберите пример по ссылке, можете использовать объетную модель типа `BindingList<Order>`, и в нее же и дерсереализоваться из XML (или наоборот), и ее же прикрутить к DGV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по скриншотам, вы изначально создали колонки в DataGridView (с правильными заголовками на русском).

И сперва вы добавляете значения в ячейки вручную. А потом при поиске уже используете привязку данных к DataSource. При этом автоматически добавляются новые колонки.

Чтобы новые колонки не добавлялись, нужно задать маппинг колонок датагрида к источнику данных. Делается это с помощью свойства [DataPropertyName](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname).

Например, так может выглядеть код для колонки с хедером Дата, привязанной к колонке Date в таблице DataTable.

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Date", "Дата");
dataGridView1.Columns["Date"].DataPropertyName = "Date";
```

Задайте DataPropertyName для всех колонок. Это можно сделать и в дизайнере.

---

Код поиска у вас по сути правильный и рабочий, но я бы его немного упростил.

```
private void toolStriptbxSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filterField = "Service";
    dataTableOrders.DefaultView.RowFilter =
        string.Format("[{0}] LIKE '%{1}%'", filterField, toolStriptbxSearch.Text);
}
```

Убираем постоянную загрузку данных.

Делаем в классе формы поля:

```
private DataSet dataSet;
private DataTable dataTableOrders;
```

В том месте, где осуществляется первоначальная загрузка данных, пишем:

```
dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(Properties.Settings.Default.XMLDBFile);
dataTableOrders = dataSet.Tables["Orders"];
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTableOrders;
```

Цикл `foreach` убираем.

К этим полям теперь можно свободно обращаться во всех методах формы. Что и делается в обработчике события.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ, да это работает, даже лучше чем было, но теперь я не могу добавить новые записи в DVG программно. Получается мне нужно их добавить сразу же в XML и заново прочитать его?

Comment: @Алексей - Нет, добавляйте записи в `DataTable`, который привязан к гриду. То есть в `dataTableOrders`.

Comment: Т.е. так:
`int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dataTableOrders);
dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();`?

Comment: Понял как добавлять, спасибо!